# How can I make a parser group lists at the end of every element?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, size

I have created a method which is intended to parse XML data which contains coordinates of locations. The format of the XML data is as such:

```
// Coordinates are of the form '-180,90,0 -120,60,0 -90,45,0 ...'
<LineString>
 <coordinates>
   coordinate1 coordinate2 coordinate3...
 </coordinates>
</LineString>
<LineString>
 <coordinates>
   coordinate11 coordinate12 coordinate13...
 </coordinates>
</LineString>
<LineString>
 <coordinates>
   coordinate29 coordinate30 coordinate31... //(# of coordinates is different per list)
 </coordinates>
</LineString>
... etc
```

It correctly parses the XML file but I seem to have made an error where the size of the list the coordinate is stored in is the total number of coordinates (292), whereas I intended it to be the number of LineStrings (9).

This is the method I have created to parse the data:

```
if(qName.equals("coordinates")) {
 String[] splitspace = accumulator.toString().trim().split(" ");
 Segment listcoords = new Segment();

 for (String s : splitspace) {
   strarray = s.split(",");
   Double strarray1 = Double.parseDouble(strarray[0]);
   Double strarray2 = Double.parseDouble(strarray[1]);
   Coordinates coord = new Coordinates(strarray1, strarray2);
   listcoords.addPoint(coord); //addPoint takes two coordinates to create an object Coordinates
   route.addSegment(listcoords); //addSegment takes lists of coordinates and adds them to a Segment which is a list of Coordinates.
}
```

Can anyone help pinpoint how I can change the size of segments from 292 to 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a minor change is required:

```
if(qName.equals("coordinates")) {
    String[] splitspace = accumulator.toString().trim().split(" ");
    Segment listcoords = new Segment();

    for (String s : splitspace) {
        String[] strarray = s.split(",");
        Double strarray1 = Double.parseDouble(strarray[0]);
        Double strarray2 = Double.parseDouble(strarray[1]);
        Coordinates coord = new Coordinates(strarray1, strarray2);
        listcoords.addPoint(coord); 
    }
    // now the Segment list listcoords is complete and can be added to the global list of list
    route.addSegment(listcoords);
}
```